# Maple loop print only prime inputs

Tags: maple

I'm new to maple and attempted to write code to print the results of a certain equations given that the input variable was prime. The code gives no error, but doesn't work.

for n from 3 by 2 to 99 do if isprime(n) then print*(n, ifactor((2^n+1)*(1/3))) end if end do;

Answer (score 4):

Why the * after print?  You're using print as a name, not calling it. 
I think you want

```
for n from 3 by 2 to 99 do
  if isprime(n) then print(n, ifactor((2^n+1)/3)) end if
end do;
```

EDIT: This problem can arise when using the default 2D input if you accidentally put a space after the "print".

$$ print(n, ifactor(2^n+1)/3)) $$ is ok, but
$$ print\; (n, ifactor(2^n+1)/3)) $$
is not.  A space is interpreted here as an implied multiplication.
Unfortunately, it's hard to notice such spaces unless you look very carefully.  One of the reasons I much prefer 1D Maple input to 2D input.